# Shell script on Raspberry Pi fails to copy files from usb0 to directory

Tags: shell-script, raspberry-pi, raspbian, cp

I am trying to write a shell script to copy specific files from an archive USB thumb drive to my Rasberry Pi 4b. The script is, in my opinion, brain dead simple.

```
cp /media/usb0/archive/file1.zip /home/pi/app/files/
cp /media/usb0/archive/file2.zip /home/pi/app/files/

ls -Fal /home/pi/app/files/
```

I get no error messages but neither `file1.zip` nor `file2.zip` can be found in `/home/pi/app/files/`

If file2.zip can't be found on the USB drive, I get this error message, as I expect.

```
cp: Cannot stat '/media/usb0/archive/file2.zip': No such file or directory
```

This means that the script is executing. Yay for that!

What am I missing here? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

I edited the script to look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
cp /media/usb0/archive/file1.zip /home/pi/app/files/
cp /media/usb0/archive/file2.zip /home/pi/app/files/
ls -Fal /home/pi/app/files/
```

Output of the script is `/media/usb0/copy.sh: 2: set: Illegal option-`

Comment: "_This means that the script is executing_" no, it means that `cp` isn't reporting an error. Near the top of the script (ideally just after the first line `#!` marker that defines the script interpreter) add `set -x`. Now run the script again. Can you see your `cp` statements being executed?

Comment: Adding `set -x`  to the second line the error out with `/media/usb0/copy.sh: 2: set: Illegal option -`

Comment: It could be Windows line endings.  Shell scripts must be saved with unix line endings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

And solved!

It was the Windows line termination getting in the way. Converted it to Unix line termination, using Notepad++'s End Of Line conversion feature, and it worked like a charm.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to convert a file from Windows endings to Unix endings is to execute `dos2unix` (available in apt, etc).

When working on Windows, Sublime Text could be a solution too: in the menu bar, View -> Line endings -> Unix, should do the trick.

Comment: here a custom plugin to make Sublime Text line ending defaults to Unix: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/is-there-any-way-to-convert-files-line-ending-on-saving/25456/4

Comment: @amber please **accept** the answer that solved the problem. this marks the question as "done" and it no longer shows up in the list of problems that "need attention"

Comment: @umläute It wanted me to wait to mark it as the answer until tomorrow.

Comment: @mark93 I just used Notepad++'s Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Unix feature. It was super convenient as I already had it and had been editing the script in it to begin with.

Comment: @amber how about accepting an answer that is not your own?

Comment: @umläute Because the answer that is not my own doesn't actually identify the root of the problem. Rather, it is a suggestion on how to implement the solution I already identified below. While it's useful in its own right as tool suggestions usually are and the reason I up-voted the answer, it doesn't provide the solution.